# Jenkins declarative pipeline using regex 101

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm new to declarative pipeline and exploring its features. I tried to use regex. The following example is the result of trial and error. Is there a nicer solution out there? I'm looking for a new shiny *declarative pipeline way*, if there is any.

**What I do not get is, why do I have to use the `script{}-Enviroment` and why do I have to use a local variable (`def matcherX`)?**

*working example followed by first attemts:*

### Working Example:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        dummyText = 'aaa123aaa'
        transfare = ''
    }
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('regex') {
            steps{
                script{
                    def matcherX = dummyText =~ /(\d+)/
                    transfare = matcherX[0][0]
                    echo transfare     // results in 123
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

### Error: without a script{}

```
/*
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 11: Expected a step @ line 11, column 21.
                       def matcherX = dummyText =~ /(\d+)/
                       ^
WorkflowScript: 12: Expected a step @ line 12, column 21.
                       transfare = matcherX[0][0]
*/
```

### Error: with script but with a global variable

```
//script{
//                    transfare = dummyText =~ /(\d+)/
/*

// No line displayed where error occured???                    
an exception which occurred:
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.withscript.WithScriptScript.script
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript@192ebed
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@31fd6bc8
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@609aa9b5
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@3e51c1c3
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@3e51c1c3
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script block indicates departure from the pure declarative syntax.  Ideally builds (just as any other process) could take advantage of a pure declarative syntax to avoid implicit dependencies between steps.

The global variable of a matcher type fails to serialize which is needed to pass it between the Jenkins master and the slave (I guess).

Comment: thx for picking up this post!
Can you be more specific about 'serialize'?

Comment: `Since pipelines must survive Jenkins restarts, the state of the running program is periodically saved to disk so it can be resumed later (saves occur after every step or in the middle of steps such as sh`. https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables  (as referred by https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit#note-on-cps).